# Rails Hartl Tutorial: Getting an SSL error every time I go to the page to activate a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following along Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and I've seem to hit a wall in Chapter 11 [Link to relevant section.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#fig-activated_user)  I'm running this from my own computer, so I'm visiting localhost:3000.  I create a new user via the signup page in the app, and I can check the rails server logs to see the email that is generated with the link for activation.  However, when I follow the link I get an error in chrome (and other browsers as well) saying:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> localhost sent an invalid response.
>
> Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

My server logs state:

```
2017-06-01 21:03:21 -0400: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #
<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2017-06-01 21:03:21 -0400: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#<IO:
<STDERR>>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, 
"rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", 
"SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"puma 3.4.0 Owl Bowl 
Brawl", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
```

I've tried turning off my firewall, resetting my cache and cookies, and other solutions I found on the web, but nothing seems to do the trick.  I know common practice is to give relevant snippets of application code, but I honestly don't even know where to begin with that.  If there's any files you need to see, then I'll be happy to post them.  Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to hit https://localhost:3000? if so, just stick with http://localhost:3000 — it's local, so you're fine. Make sure you don't have `config.force_ssl = true` anywhere, too.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same Problem and it took me some time to solve it. Probably You solved it by now.
So to save others the time finding the solution, I just want to share it here. The solution is to just hit localhost:3000 without the https:// 
This way there is now ssl decryption/parsing involved, which is not necessary in development and will only cause a parsing error.

Best Sebastian